# Regx + Java : split a text into words and removing punctuation only if they are alone or at the end

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string into words but I want to keep, "a.b.c" as a word, and remove the punctuation only if it is alone or at the end of a word
e.g.

```
"a.b.c" --> "a.b.c"
"a.b."  --> "a.b"
```

e.g

```
String str1 = "abc a.b a. .  b, , test"; should return "abc","a.b","a","b","test"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String str1 = "abc a.b a. .  b, , test";
String[] toks = str1.split("\\p{Punct}*\\s+[\\s\\p{Punct}]*");
for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf(">>> [%s]%n", tok);

>>> [abc]
>>> [a.b]
>>> [a]
>>> [b]
>>> [test]
```

Comment: can you explain your regex for me?

Comment: It splits on 0 or more punctuation chars followed by 1 or more spaces and again followed by 0 or more space or punctuation. Thus giving us the ability to split on punctuation chars at start or end of the words.

Comment: This works great! But how to remove punctuation if it's not followed by space and is the end of the line for example?

Comment: @anubhava Thank you. It works this way, but need to execute both regex, from your answer to this Q and answer you gave me now, to make it work. Otherwise, if I just replace punctuation and split into words after, it leaves punctuation after words that followed by whitespace.

Comment: Sorry comment is not really a section for asking new question. Please post a question with your requirements and we'll answer it.